# How to prove a certain inequality for a complex valued function using its derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, inequality, derivatives, supremum-and-infimum

I have the following question:

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ be an arbitrary, but fixed natural number, let $f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}:\ t\mapsto n^{-b} - t^{-b}$, when $b\in \mathbb{C}$ denotes a fixed complex number with Re$(b)>0$.

> How can I prove that $\sup\limits_{n\leq t \leq n+1} \{|f(t)|\}\leq \frac{|b|}{n^{1+ \text{Re}(b)}}$ ?

I know that the derivative of $f$ is given by $\frac{b}{t^{b+1}}$, but I'm not sure, what theorems stay valid, because we have a complex valued function $f$ here.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f\colon(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{C}$ be given by
$$
f(x)=x^{-b}=e^{-b\log x},
$$
where $\log$ is the principal branch of the logarithm, that is, $\log x$ is real and $\log 1=0$.
Then $f$ is $C^\infty$ and
$$
f'(x)=-b\,e^{-b\log x}\,\frac1x=-b\,e^{-(b+1)\log x}=-b\,x^{-(b+1)}.
$$
Now
$$
|t^{-b}-t^{-b}|=|f(t)-f(n)|=\Bigl|\int_n^tf'(x)\,dx\Bigr|\le |b|\int_n^{n+1}|x^{-(b+1)}|\,dx\le\frac{|b|}{n^{\operatorname{Re}(b)+1}}.
$$
Note: $f(t)-f(n)=\int_n^tf'(x)\,dx$ can be justified integrating the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! :-)